# Use LUIS intent recognition with Webspeech

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-recognition, azure-language-understanding, webspeech-api

Hi I'm trying to use luis.ai intent recognition with WebSpeech API instead of using cognitive speech service in a nodejs application.

Is there any known way to do that? Please help

Comment: Direct Line service for the Direct Line and Web Chat channels. You can use Direct Line Speech, which combines Direct Line and Cognitive Speech capabilities for substantially improved performance for speech customers over the existing client-side speech integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so I just went and used the rest API